# I have an error for import package in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages, dart-packages, flutter-run

Tips:

(Sorry for mistakes. English isn't my native language)

(I'm new in flutter)

I have many errors in my flutter project. I think that's because of packages. when I write: `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`, android studio draw a red line under it that means error and when I hold down the mouse pointer on import package, It says: `Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter/material.dart'` I think that's why all of the error. How can I fix it?

My errors:

```
error: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter/material.dart'. (uri_does_not_exist at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:1)

error: The function 'runApp' isn't defined. (undefined_function at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:3)

error: Classes can only extend other classes. (extends_non_class at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:5)

error: Undefined class 'Widget'. (undefined_class at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:8)

error: Undefined class 'BuildContext'. (undefined_class at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:8)

error: The method 'MaterialApp' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp'. (undefined_method at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:9)

error: Classes can only extend other classes. (extends_non_class at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:16)

error: Undefined class 'Widget'. (undefined_class at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:19)

error: Undefined class 'BuildContext'. (undefined_class at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:19)

error: The method 'Material' isn't defined for the type 'MyScaffold'. (undefined_method at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:20)

error: The method 'Column' isn't defined for the type 'MyScaffold'. (undefined_method at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:21)

error: The name 'Widget' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument. (non_type_as_type_argument at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:22)

error: The name 'Row' isn't a class. (creation_with_non_type at [untitled6]     bin\main.dart:23)

error: The name 'IconButton' isn't a class. (creation_with_non_type at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:24)

error: The method 'Icon' isn't defined for the type 'MyScaffold'. (undefined_method at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:25)

error: Undefined name 'Icons'. (undefined_identifier at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:25)

error: The name 'Text' isn't a class. (creation_with_non_type at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:29)

error: The name 'IconButton' isn't a class. (creation_with_non_type at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:30)

error: The method 'Icon' isn't defined for the type 'MyScaffold'. (undefined_method at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:32)

error: Undefined name 'Icons'. (undefined_identifier at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:32)

error: Expected to find ')'. (expected_token at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:37)

error: Expected to find ']'. (expected_token at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:38)

error: Expected to find ')'. (expected_token at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:38)

error: Expected to find ')'. (expected_token at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:39)

info: The method doesn't override an inherited method. (override_on_non_overriding_member at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:8)

info: Unnecessary new keyword. (unnecessary_new at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:11)

info: The method doesn't override an inherited method. (override_on_non_overriding_member at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:19)

info: Unnecessary new keyword. (unnecessary_new at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:23)

info: Unnecessary new keyword. (unnecessary_new at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:24)

info: Unnecessary new keyword. (unnecessary_new at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:29)

info: Unnecessary new keyword. (unnecessary_new at [untitled6] bin\main.dart:30)
```

Could you please help me? My work has been delayed for a few days

Comment: Try `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get`

Comment: Also make sure you added the package to the project first. The easiest way is by issuing `flutter pub add <package>` from a terminal in your project dir. You can check which packages are installed by inspecting your `pubspec.yaml` file. Good luck!

Comment: You go now terminal and run this `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that something is messed up in the references that the Flutter project uses. You can run either `flutter clean` or `flutter pub cache repair` to help rebuild the references used in the project, then run `flutter pub get` to download the configured plugins.

Answer (score 1):

try this steps:

```
> flutter clean

> flutter pub get

> flutter pub upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I removed Flutter and reinstalled it. the issue is gone.